# Continuity of $f$ doesn't imply differentiability

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, epsilon-delta

I am currently working with Steward's book "Calculus". I found the following proof for the

**Theorem:** If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $f$ is continuous at $a$.

**Proof:** By assumption

$$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a}$$

exists. Thus we can write

$$\begin{align} \lim_{x \to a} \left[ f(x) - f(a) \right] 
& = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a} \left( x-a \right) \\ 
& = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a} \cdot \lim_{x \to a} \left( x-a \right) \\
& = f'(a) \cdot 0 = 0\end{align}$$

Now we have

$$\begin{align} \lim_{x \to a}f(x)
& = \lim_{x \to a} \left[ f(a) + \left( f(x) - f(a) \right) \right] \\
& = \lim_{x \to a} f(a) + \lim_{x \to a} \left[\left( f(x) - f(a) \right) \right] \\
& = f(a) + 0 = f(a)\end{align}$$

Therefore $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$. $\blacksquare$

Now I came upon the idea, to work this proof backwards and try to see, where it fails. It should fail, since continuity of $f$ doesn't imply differentiability. I post my train of thoughts here and ask, if I am correct.

From $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a)$, which is given by continuity of $f$, we can deduce that $\lim_{x \to a} f(a) =f(a)$. This is intuitively correct. Using a delta-epsilon-argument, working from

$$ 0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon $$

we have

$$ 0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(a) - f(a)| < \epsilon $$

which is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, regardless of $\delta$.

Now we can use the same intermediate step as above:

$$\begin{align} \lim_{x \to a} \left[ f(x) - f(a) \right] 
& = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a} \left( x-a \right) \\ 
& = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a} \cdot \lim_{x \to a} \left( x-a \right) \\
& = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a} \cdot 0 = 0\end{align}$$

Now, my first impulse was to say that $\lim_{x \to a} \left[ f(x) - f(a) \right] = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a} \cdot 0$ is true for all values of $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a}$ so that we cannot make any statements about it's value. But I think this not correct, since if $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a}$ doesn't exist, the whole equation is not defined. So I think it is better to say that, from here we can't go any further, since $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a} \cdot 0 = 0$ doesn't give any information on the existence or value of $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a}$.

Now I ask in particular about my assumption $\lim_{x \to a} f(a) = f(a)$ and my statement regarding $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a} \cdot 0 = 0$ not giving any information on the existence or value of $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a}$. Is my terminology correct there? When writing about math, I found that small digressions in terminology can lead to wrong arguments, so I want to be sure here.

Sorry if this seems silly, but the idea caught my mind and I wanted to see, how far I could go in working the above proof backwards. Now I need to know, if my reasoning is correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, @David C. Ullrich, you misunderstood. I started from a proof, that differentiability implies continuity. I tried to work this proof backwards, to see where and how exactly this would fail. My question was, if my reasoning as to how it failed, was correct. Sorry if this was confusing.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Please note my edit. Did a wrong click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right: from the fact that$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}(x-a)=0,$$you cannot deduce that$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\cdot\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)=0.\tag1\label a$$The equality \eqref{a} assumes that both limits that appear there exist, and you have no reason no assume that.

More generally, the equality$$\lim_{x\to a}\bigl(f(x)g(x)\bigr)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\cdot\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$holds if both limits $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist, but the existence of $\lim_{x\to a}\bigl(f(x)g(x)\bigr)$ doesn't allow you to deduce that the limits at $a$ of $f$ and $g$ exist.

On the other hand, you need no assumption whatsoever about $f$ (other than the fact that $a$ belongs to its domain) to know that $\lim_{x\to a}f(a)=f(a)$. For *any* constant function $\lambda$ and *any* $a\in\Bbb R$, $\lim_{x\to a}\lambda=\lambda$.